How to realize no response from the com port?
According to the idea, the program should connect to the device via a com port. If there is no response, a message should appear stating that the device is out of touch. The message cannot be received using the event listener. How do I implement the logic for outputting a no connection message?
import jssc.*;


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ComPortOperation {

   private static SerialPort serialPort;
   private static int baudRate;
   private static String portName;
   private static ArrayList<Integer> codes = new ArrayList<>();
    static int[] dataInt;


    public static void connect(int number) throws SerialPortException {
        System.out.println(MainView.getItemSuperComboBox());
        serialPort = new SerialPort(portName);
        serialPort.openPort();
        serialPort.setParams(baudRate,
                SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                SerialPort.PARITY_EVEN);
        serialPort.setEventsMask(SerialPort.MASK_RXCHAR);
        serialPort.addEventListener(new SerialPortReader(serialPort));
       
        serialPort.writeIntArray(number);
      

    }

      static class SerialPortReader implements SerialPortEventListener {

       private SerialPort serialPort;

       public SerialPortReader(SerialPort serialPort){
           this.serialPort = serialPort;
       }
        public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {

           if(!event.isRXCHAR()) {
               System.out.println("No connection"); // never reaches
           }

               try {
                  dataInt = serialPort.readIntArray(1, 500);
                 
               } catch (SerialPortException e) {
                   System.out.println(e);

               } catch (SerialPortTimeoutException e) {

                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

        }
    }

}


When you try to start the program, it just occupies the port without performing any actions.
I tried to find realization of this problem on jssc lybrary examples, but not succesfully :(

Have you checked to see if your serialEvent() function is ever even receiving any events to begin with? This code seems to be predicated on the assumption that there is present activity on the port.

when trying to connect to a real device, the response is present. Thank you for responding.
